# Any software available to turn a nokia e71 into an WIFI Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, nokia-e-series

My partner has a Nokia E71 and an iPod Touch and I was wondering if its possible to get the Nokia to share its 3G internet connection via the WIFI by becoming an Access Point.

Googling for E71 and Access Point just gets me people who want to connect the phone to an access point as opposed to turning it into one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There most definitely is.

[JokuSpot](http://www.joikushop.com/) does exactly what you are after:

> Connect your laptop to internet via WiFi using your mobile phone's 3G. JoikuSpot shares your phones 3G over WiFi. Premium supports all internet and email protocols, VPN, and connection security.

There is a free and a premium version available. Premium enables you to use the wifi connection for more than just web browsing.