# Use Nokia E71 (USB) as cellular modem on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: internet-connection, nokia-e-series, cellular-internet

Is there a way to use my E71 as a cellular modem on Ubuntu 8.04? I'm using a USB cable to eliminate any Bluetooth problems, and prefer USB over [Wi-Fi sharing solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/91100/any-software-available-to-turn-a-nokia-e71-into-an-wifi-access-point).

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [my question at whatsup.org.il](http://whatsup.org.il/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=337664#337664), the solution seems to be configuring `wvdial.conf` as:

```
[Dialer usb] 
;Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 
init1 = AT+CGDCONT=1,”IP”,”orange.co.il” 
Modem Type = USB Modem 
Phone = *99# 
ISDN = 0 
Username = ” “ 
Init1 = ATZ 
Password = ” ” 
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0 
Baud = 460800
```

You might want to change 'orange.co.il' to your provider's url. Actually, I was just guessing mine - I'm not sure the url is entirely necessary.

Now,

```
su -c "wvdial usb"
```

Some magic happens:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60 
--> Cannot get information for serial port. 
--> Initializing modem. 
--> Sending: ATZ 
ATZ 
OK 
--> Modem initialized. 
--> Sending: ATDT*99# 
--> Waiting for carrier. 
ATDT*99# 
CONNECT 
~[7f]}#@!}!} } }2}#}$@#}!}$}%\}"}&} }*} } g}%~ 
--> Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt. 
~[7f]}#@!}!} } }2}#}$@#}!}$}%\}"}&} }*} } g}%~ 
--> PPP negotiation detected. 
--> Starting pppd at Sun Jan 24 10:01:27 2010 
--> Pid of pppd: 11872 
--> Using interface ppp0 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> local  IP address 10.195.166.229 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> remote IP address 10.6.6.6 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> primary   DNS address 192.118.11.77 
--> pppd: w[7f] 
--> secondary DNS address 192.118.9.177 
--> pppd: w[7f]
```

`wvdial` stops here. Now type, in another window:

```
sudo route add default gw 110.195.166.229 ppp0
```

Of course, use the IP you've got from your provider, not the one listed here.

And you're done.